# XNA 2D Rotation HLSL

Tags: c#, xna, transformation, hlsl

So this evening I've been trying to learn HLSL but I'm having a hard time taking things in from various guides I've read online since many of them are targeted at 3D projects and involve matrixes, or are written for DX11 *though I'm sure many of you will say it's all the same*. 
The rotation parameter in the draw method is already being used so I'm hoping to use HLSL to rotate the object.
I'm not here asking for code but I feel like I'm running out of online resources.

http://blog.josack.com/2011/07/my-first-2d-pixel-shaders-part-2.html. After having read this tutorial I'm led to believe I don't need to be concerned by VertexShaderFunction and that I may be able to perform the transformation entirely in through tex2D method.

```
sampler s0;

float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 coords: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0  
{  
    float4 color = tex2D(s0, coords);  
    return color; 
} 

technique Technique1
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  What are you trying to accomplish, and what isn't working?  If you're using the built-in rotation parameter then the default vertex shader should rotate the sprite.  If you want it to do something else then you need to specify what that something else is.

Answer (score 0):

You get the original texture coordinates inside the pixel shader named 'coords' in your case.

This coordinates contain the x and y coordinate of the pixel. By adjusting this coordinates (in your case use sin, cos to rotate it) you can edit the rendered image in many ways.

So for you it would be something like: (this is just out of my mind so no idea if it really works or not)

```
float sin = sin(rotation);
float cos = cos(rotation);
float2 newcoords = coords - 0.5; //move to center
newcoords.x = (coords.x * cos) + (coords.y * (-sin));
newcoords.y = (coords.x * sin) + (coords.y * cos);
float4 color = tex2D(s0, newcoords + 0.5);
```

Keep in mind that this only rotates the content of the image so it will look not how you want if the content is not circular.
to make it work with any image you would need to do the same in the vertex shader.

good luck and happy coding :)